# GRE number theory question

Tags: number-theory

What is the greatest integer that divides $p^4-1$ for every prime $p>5$?

So I do not even understand the solution they omitted lots of detail.

So I know that

$$p^4-1=(p-1)(p+1)(p^2+1).$$

The solution says the first two factors are divisible by $2$ and $4$, one by $2$ and the other by $4$. I do not see why, and they say the last one is divisible by $2$ as well. And so they get that $2 \cdot 4 \cdot 2 = 16$ divides $p^4-1$. Is it because $p>5$ and so subtracting $1$ we get something divisible by 4?

And furthermore, why is it that by "casework" (is what they call it) we have

$$3 \mid (p^2-1)$$

and

$$5 \mid (p^2-1).$$

Putting these together clearly I see why the answer is $3 \cdot 5 \cdot 16.$ But I do not understand the steps that got me here. At first glance I thought to use wislons theorem but that does not work here does it?
Thanks in advance, some of these GRE problems are really truly something aren't they.

Comment: If $p>5$ is prime, then $p-1$ and $p+1$ are even. And obviously, one of them can be divided by $4$... Same, $p^2$ is odd, therefore $p^2+1$ is even...

Comment: thanks! forgot to assume $p>5$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $p$ is prime and $p > 5$ then it must be odd, so $p \equiv 1$ or $3 \pmod{4}$. Hence, one of $p+1$ and $p-1$ is divisible by $4$ and the other one only by $2$.

On the other hand, for any $p \neq 3$ we have $p \equiv 1,2 \pmod{3}$. It is an easy check that these are both solution to $x^2 -1 \equiv 0 \pmod{3}$.

You can do a similar thing for $5 | p^4 -1$ (it is not true $5 | p^2 -1$, try $p = 17$). A quicker way could be seeing that the group of units of $\mathbb{Z}/5 \mathbb{Z}$ is cyclic with order $4$, so the polynomial $x^4 -1$ makes the entire group vanish.

Comment: For the last step, you can casually note that all odd squares end in 1 or 9 mod 10, so either $(p^2+1)$ or $(p^2-1)$ must be divisible by 5.

Comment: wow! incredible observation!